# Validating primitive data type

Tags: java, validation, types

I was reviewing this data validation [method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnextdouble.htm) Why does the printed output below return `World!` as `true`? `World!` is not of type double

```
    public static void tutorials_Point(){
    String s = "Hello World! 3 + 3.0 = 6 ";
    double d = 1.3985;
    s=s+d;

    // create a new scanner with the specified String Object
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);

    // assign locale as US to recognize double numbers in a string
//    scanner.useLocale(Locale.US);

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        // print what is scanned
        System.out.println("" + scanner.next());

        // check if the scanner's next token is a double
        System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNextDouble());

    }

    // close the scanner
    scanner.close();
}
```

**EDIT:** I am trying to test each token as double, the method above is misleading and checks every other value. I just don't know enough java yet to complete the test:

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    // print what is scanned
    String logical = scanner.next();
    System.out.println("Checking whether " + logical + " is of type 'double' ...");

    // check if the scanner's next token is a double
    System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNextDouble());

}
```

**Output should be**

```
Checking whether Hello is of type 'double' ...
false
Checking whether World! is of type 'double' ...
false
Checking whether 3 is of type 'double' ...
true
Checking whether + is of type 'double' ...
false
Checking whether 3.0 is of type 'double' ...
true
Checking whether = is of type 'double' ...
false
Checking whether 6 is of type 'double' ...
true
Checking whether 1.3985 is of type 'double' ...
true
```

Comment: `hasNext` (Hello), yes, consume, `hasNextDouble` (World!), no. `hasNext` (World!), yes, consume, `hasNextDouble` (3), yes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What? Shouldn't I receive a false for everything except for the value `d`

Comment: Your `Scanner` contains the next token `Hello`, so `hasNext` will return true, then it will consume `Hello` with `next`. Then it will check the next token with `hasNextDouble`, the next token is `World!` so it will return and print `false`. `hasNext` will return `true` since `World!` is the next token. `next` will consume `World!` and `3` and some other characters will remain in the `Scanner`. `hasNextDouble` will check the next token, which is `3`, which can be parsed as a `double`, and will therefore return `true`.

Comment: What are you expecting it to print?

Comment: Go read the javadoc of `Scanner#next()`.

Comment: why do I enter an infinite loop when I comment out `scanner.next()` Why can I not receive 8 boolean values from `scanner.hasNextdouble()`   ?

Comment: @phillipsK Say the next thing is "Hello". If you call `hasNextDouble`, it returns false (because "Hello" is not a number) and the next thing is still "Hello" (because why would it have changed?). If you call `hasNextDouble` again, it returns false (because "Hello" is still not a number) and the next thing is still "Hello" (because why would it have changed?). And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true because the

```
 System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNextDouble());
```

is getting "Next" value after "World", it is 3. So the result would be true.
I think you should check the value when you get it out. For example:

```
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            // print what is scanned
            String currentValue = scanner.next();
            boolean isDouble = false;
            try {
                double doubleValue = Double.valueOf(currentValue);
                isDouble = true;
                System.out.println(doubleValue + " : " + isDouble);
            } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println(currentValue + " : " + isDouble);
            }
            // check if the scanner's next token is a double
//          System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNextDouble());

        }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: How could I do this with an if statement? `if (double doubleValue == Double.valueOf(currentValue)){
            
        }`?

Comment: No.. you can't do that. you have to assign the doubleValue first. You can't assign value to doubleValue in If

Comment: Is there a predefined method of the scanner class that counts tokens in the scanner.hasNext() ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's step through this, pretending we're a computer.

1. `while (scanner.hasNext()) {`

   Is there a next token? Yes (it's "Hello") so we execute the loop body.
2. `System.out.println("" + scanner.next());`

   Reads the next token ("Hello") and prints "Hello"
3. `System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNextDouble());`

   Is the next token a double? No (it's "World"), so `hasNextDouble` returns false, so prints "false".
4. End of the loop, so restart.
5. `while (scanner.hasNext()) {`

   Is there a next token? Yes (it's "World!") so we execute the loop body.
6. `System.out.println("" + scanner.next());`

   Reads the next token ("World!") and prints "World!"
7. `System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNextDouble());`

   Is the next token a double? Yes (it's "3") so `hasNextDouble` returns true, so prints "true".
8. End of the loop, so restart.

(so far we've printed `Hello`, `false`, `World!`, `true`)

And so on. The computer is doing exactly what you told it to - I don't see a problem here.

Comment: the code would be more logical to return a true or false condition based upon the preceded printed value

Comment: @phillipsK Well then it would be called `hadPreviousDouble` wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changing your while loop to this:

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    // check if the scanner's next token is a double
    boolean isNextDouble = scanner.hasNextDouble();

    // print what is scanned
    String logical = scanner.next();

    System.out.println("Checking whether " + logical + " is of type 'double' ...");
    System.out.println("" + isNextDouble);

}
```